# Keep first two items of list at top always

Tags: html, css

I want to create a list where the first two items are always at the top, regardless of scrolling. I also want the scrollbar to just encompass the remaining items in the list.

I created a fiddle of my rough idea, which is pretty much to use position fixed on the first two list items and then use padding-top on the area that the scrollbar encompasses. But it does not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/r9dg6w6j/

EDIT:

It must be done using a list please.

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item" id="first">HELLO</li>
  <li class="item" id="second">HELLO2</li>
  <li class="item">Random</li>
  <li class="item">Random</li>
  <li class="item">Random</li>
  <li class="item">Random</li>
  <li class="item">Random</li>
  <li class="item">Random</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#first {
  color: red;
  position:fixed;
  top: 20px;
}

#second {
  color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
}

.list {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.item {
  color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: does it have to be a single list?

Comment: Yes sir! This is a much simplified example of the actual problem aha

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea with the fixed position hack is close.  Try using `margin-top` instead of padding.  [Modified fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/r9dg6w6j/3/)

Comment: Oh that is weird! I see it on my fiddle and yours now, but on my project margin-top was not moving the scrollbar down it kept it the same length still. It must be something else then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How can I do this just for the list scroll and keep them moving normally for the page scroll. Position fixed will fix this for the whole view port and moving the page up and down for more content. These always stay at the same place. Any ideas on this ???

Comment: Wrap them in a relatively positioned container?  But you should probably ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

changing it to margin-top works in your fiddle:

```
  margin-top: 120px;
```